# narrowing down rows added on a date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

I have the following statement:

```
select count(*), FirstAdded from db.table where date(FirstAdded) between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-10' group by Firstadded order by count(*)
```

when i execute it, it returns data for every time a row has been added to the table.

```
1 | 2013-07-03 15:22:14
1 | 2013-07-03 15:23:14
1 | 2013-07-03 15:22:42
1 | 2013-07-03 15:45:29
```

I would like to arrogate this down to the amount of rows added daily (without the m:s time, just for the entire day). e.g.

```
345  | 2013-07-03 
7482 | 2013-07-04
1237 | 2013-07-05
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is a `group by` query:

```
select date(FirstAdded), count(*)
from db.table
group by date(FirstAdded);
```

The function `date()` converts the datetime value to just a date value, which seems to be what you want.

Your complete query would be:

```
select count(*), date(FirstAdded)
from db.table
where date(FirstAdded) between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-10'
group by date(Firstadded)
order by count(*)
```